# Where should I set binding's maxReceivedMessageSize in Lightswitch

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am connecting to a WCF service using the technique described by [Dan Moyer](http://danlmoyer.com/?p=130).

The problem is I am receiving the "Maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded." exception. The maxReceivedMessageSize is set to max value in the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file in Lightswitch WCF proxy project so I figure it's not the right place.

Hence my question. Where is the WCF binding's configuration in a Lightswitch application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK sorry, I found the answer myself!

It seems that the proxy class actually creates a Binding object itself and doesn't use the xml configuration.

What I had to do was set the MaxBufferSize and MaxReceivedMessageSize properties for that binding object, which is then passed to the client class.

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding
              {
                  MaxBufferSize = MaxMessageSize,
                  MaxReceivedMessageSize = MaxMessageSize
              };
```